# "Missing ; before statement." in Google Sheets Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

With the Macro I want to Copy data from one sheet to another. The purpose of the script is to recognize the Project ID that is selected, set a filter in the other sheet so only the rows with the specific Project ID are copied.

I get the error message "Missing ; before statement. (line 49, file "macros")" in Line 49.

Here is how my script looks right now:

```
  //Counting variable i
  var i = 1;

  //Array with all PID´s
  var HideValues = [0,1];

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  //Set active sheet to Visualization
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Visualization'), true);

  //Variable with selected PID
  var SelectedPID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C1').getValue();

  //Set active sheet to PID
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('PID'), true);

  //Variables with row and column to go through all PID´s
  var row = 2;
  var col = 1;

  //Add all PID´s to an array
  while (i < 500) {
  HideValues.push(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, col  ).getValue());
  i++;
  row++;
  }

  //Set active sheet to TEM Tool Data
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TEM Tool Data'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'TEM Tool Data\'!E1').activate();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria(); 

  //Remove all PID´s from the filter
  While (i<500){                              //Line with the error message
  .setHiddenValues([HideValues[i-1]])
  .build();
  i++;
  }  

  //Add selected PID to the filter
  .setVisibleValues([SelectedPID])
  .build();

  //Filter
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, criteria);

  //Copy filtered area
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2:I1386').activate();

  //Set active sheet to Visualization
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Visualization'), true);

  //Paste
  spreadsheet.getRange('A5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'TEM Tool Data\'!A2:I1386').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('J3').activate();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- you are calling `setHiddenValues()` and `setVisibleValues()` on *nothing*. I don't know what you mean to call them on, maybe `criteria` or `spreadsheet`?
- the `while` keyword must be all lowercase ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while)).

  See in the example below that using `While` (capitalised) does not work:

  ```js
  While (true) {}
  ```

Comment: And see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder.html#withcriteriacriteria,-args) how to build a filter criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You must have `while` be all lowercase, and you are missing a semicolon on `.setHiddenValues([HideValues[i-1]])` which is causing your error.